# Why librocket was abandoned and why librocket/rmlui are not used widely?

Tags: librocket

Html + css are very nice way of building ui. Despite this why librocket or rmlui are not used widely? Are there any drawbacks of using html + css (librocket or rmlui) that people still go with wxwidgets etc.